# Search Multiple Words PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

UPDATE:

I got a little farther with:

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']); 
$keywords = explode(" ", $query); 
foreach ($keywords as $keys) { 
$search_sql .= " AND Name LIKE '%$keys%' "; 
}
```

But it's still returning nothing.

I couldn't find this because I wasn't sure on how to word it. Basically, when a user queries my database I want to return the card, but if the user misses one word that's in the middle (say he queries Elesh Norn Foil, since they didn't query Elesh Norn, Grand Cenobite Foil exactly the Grand Cenobite trips my program up and returns nothing).

So:

-Johnny types "Elesh Norn" he returns "Elesh Norn, Grand Cenobite" and "Elesh Norn, Grand Cenobite Foil"

-However, if Johnny types "Elesh Norn Foil" it returns with a "No card found!" match

Here's my query statement:

```
SELECT Name, Amount, CardID FROM modernmasters WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
```

So what would I have to change my query to so my search doesn't get tripped up?

Comment: split the search terms on space, the n search for each with an OR - or use full text searches

Comment: Searching with an OR would return all sorts of results are are probably not relevant. I'd use an AND.

Comment: @HoboSapiens but and FOIL would then fail the first match he wants

Comment: Thanks for this guys, would I do this by doing explode, or how would I do it?

Comment: You really shouldn't use mysql_ functions nowadays.

Comment: I know, it's mysqli nowadays but unfortunately I looked up an old YouTube video based on an older version of PHP when I was teaching myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this. Hope it will help.

```
$search_sql = "SELECT Name, Amount, CardID FROM modernmasters WHERE";
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']); 
$keywords = explode(" ", $query); 
$keyCount = 0;
foreach ($keywords as $keys) { 
    if ($keyCount > 0){
        $search_sql .= " AND";
    }
    $search_sql .= " Name LIKE '%$keys%'"; 
    ++$keyCount;
}
```